# I need to find if the second string and first string are substrings of each other

Tags: java

The first two if statements work correctly but the third one doesn't work and crashes my program.
First String: Taco Bell
Second String: Taco

program crashes.

It should say that the second string is substring of the first string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class module_4_assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first string value: ");

        String first_string = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter second string value: ");

        String second_string = input.nextLine();

        if (first_string.equals(second_string)) {

            System.out.println("The first string value and the second string value are equal");
        }
        else if (first_string.equals(second_string.substring(0,first_string.length()))) {

            System.out.println("The first string value is a substring of the second string value");
        }
        else if ((first_string.substring(0,second_string.length())).equals(second_string)) {

            System.out.println("The second string value is a substring of the first string value");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your program shouldn't crash, it should throw an error that will give you some clue as to what's going wrong. Try wrapping your code in a try--catch block...

Comment: If the first string is longer than the second string, then what happens when you try to find that length of substring in the second string? `"taco".substring(0, 10)`

Comment: It will be better to use [String#contains](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-contains) for substring checking